# Cannot change month in jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use the jQuery UI widget datepicker. It mostly works except that the 'Prev'/'Next' links do nothing. 'Today' works and selecting a day works.  The field is:

```
<input id="TransferDate" name="TransferDate" type="text" value="1/2/2013" />
```

And the setup call is:

```
$('[Name="TransferDate"]').datepicker({
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            showAnim: '',
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImage: '/images/calendar.gif',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            stepMonths: 1,
            onClose: function(dateText, inst){
                    $('[Name="TransferDate"]').val(dateText);
                    },
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
                    $('[Name="TransferDate"]').val(dateText);
                    }
});
```

Looking at the generate HTML, the button icons are wrapped in the appropriate  tags:

```
<a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all"
  onclick="DP_jQuery_1370007056335.datepicker._adjustDate('#TransferDate', +1, 'M');"
  title="Next">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Next</span>
</a>
```

What could stop the working?

As you can see, I've tried setting 'stepMonths' explicitly and (not shown) tried adding a `.on('change', function(){$(this).blur();});`

At other places on the same page, the datepicker works. This is in a dialog box and only seems to partially work.

It's using jquery-1.7-mis.js and jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js. As it's parts of a larger project, changing the versions is probably not an option.

Comment: Seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fEar5/

Comment: Is it any browser specific issue ??

Comment: @j08691: I know it works in jsFiddle. I tried it there myself.(http://jsfiddle.net/StarNamer/JM2Ej/). The browser's Chrome. As I said, the page actually has datepciker working elsewhere on the same page; this is in a dialog box (which is why I initially looked an the 'blur' fix). I'm stumped as to what could be stopping it and was hoping someone could point to something obvious. I'd rather not have to step through a load of jQuery code to identify the problem.

Comment: If the code you posted above doesn't exhibit then you'll need to add the code that does. It would also help if you could create a jsFiddle that showed the problem, otherwise we're left to guess.

Comment: @j08691: As I said, I was hoping someone else had seen this and could simply say "you must have (un)set the ???? parameter". The lines shown comes from a 400 line Razor file and a 300 line Javascript file which are part of a much larger project and I wanted to circumvent hours of stripping out code to locate the problem.

Comment: @RakeshChouhan: Fails exactly the same way in Chrome 27, FireFox 15, safari 5.1.7 and IE 10, so it's probably not a browser issue.